# Suggested tag-only edit got rejected. Is this correct?

Tags: discussion, tags, review-queues, edits

I lurk in on the [serial-port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serial-port) tag a lot and sometimes see questions which are about USB. I guess people think it is the universal serial bus and so it is related. But the [serial-port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serial-port) tag summary states:

> A serial port is a physical interface through which data is transferred (uni- or bidirectionally) one bit at a time. The term usually refers to the RS-232 port with a 9-pin d-sub connector that was once the standard serial interface on a PC.

I assumed that this would exclude USB since [usb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/usb) has its own tag.

So I edited one of those questions to remove the [serial-port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serial-port) tag and it got rejected ([edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23857756)).

My question is: Was this rejection correct? Shouldn't I have edited this question?

Maybe another question is, should the [serial-port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serial-port) tag also include USB and Bluetooth in its summary, since those often use the same libraries in C and Java?

EDIT:

I just noticed that the more detailed tag summary states:

> A serial port is a physical interface through which data is
>   transferred (uni- or bidirectionally) one bit at a time. The term
>   usually refers to the RS-232 port with a 9-pin d-sub connector that
>   was once the standard serial interface on a PC. Serial port may also
>   refer to the logic-level interface of a UART on a SBC (single board
>   computer). Other types of interfaces that use "serial" transfer (such
>   as USB, SATA, SPI, I2C, and TWI) should not be called "serial port",
>   but by their proper protocol name.
>
> Largely superseded in the consumer market by USB, serial connections
>   are still commonly used in many other specialist applications. Typical
>   applications include scientific/medical instruments, industrial
>   controllers and server diagnostics.
>
> More information:
>
> ```
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232
> ```

So I guess the discussion if USB is meant to be taged [serial-port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serial-port) is answered now.

Comment: At the very least you could've tidied up punctuation and grammar.

Comment: Also, given the comment [link](https://github.com/linklayer/pyvit/blob/0192c92f6888747e7daf3dc6c5aa4a6c4768f635/pyvit/hw/cantact.py), and the link to [docs](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html), it appears it *does* use a serial interface, reviewers aren't meant to be experts so you need to be clear as to why it was tagged wrongly. Also, *"was tagged serial-port due to the usage of usb"* - How do you know? They may have tagged it purposefully because they use a serial connection

Comment: You are right, I should have had a closer look at punctuation. This is another example of a library that provides functionality for serial ports and USB. But in the Question is stated, that they use USB.

Comment: From the question that's not *100%* clear to me (although you *appear* to be right), although I stand by the fact that there was plenty more to fix in the post, and an edit fixing *all* of the issues would be more likely to be approved (no promises though :) ).

Comment: Overall that tag wiki excerpt is very bad, it has no guidance on [how and when to use the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts). Serialports as physical interface seem too me more like "General computing" on Stack Overflow I assume it's used when you use serial port in your code (send/receive). Conclusion before your question can be answer we need to write a correct tag excerpt that defines when and how to use the tag

Comment: Yes, I concede that the edit was lazy.. But I think that the tag summary should be changed too.

Comment: I'm not referring to your edit, I'm referring to the fact that the tag wiki excerpt is bad, it has no guidance whatsoever on how to use the tag (personally I think it should only be used if you use serial port in code, even if it is connect via usb), if you have a general problem on serial-port probably General Computing is better then SO

Comment: *hence, before anyone can answer this question, the tag wiki excerpt needs to fixed*

Comment: So... consensus?

Comment: The question is: Do we want [tag:serial-port] only to represent the RS232 standard (by the way [tag:RS232] is a synonym of this tag).

Comment: serial-port and USB are two different things. So your edit was correct.